# How to sum up (W * H) of 3D matrix and store it in 1D matrix with length=depth(third dimension of input matrix)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to sum up all elements (W * H) of 3D matrix and store it in 1D matrix with length=depth(third dimension of input matrix)

To make myself clear:
Input dimension = 1D in the form of (W * H * D).
Required output = 1D again with length=D

let's consider below 3D Matrix : 2 x 3 x 2.

```
 Layer 1       Layer 2
[1, 2, 3      [7, 8, 9
4, 5, 6]      10, 11, 12]
```

output is 1D : `[21, 57]`

I am new to python and wrote like this:

```
 def test(w, h, c, image_inp):
     output = [image_inp[j * w + k] for i in enumerate(image_inp)
         for j in range(0,h)
             for k in range(0,w)
                 #image_inp[j * w + k] comment
                 ]
     printout(output)
```

I know this will copy the input array as it is to output array.
also output array length is not equal to Depth.

Some one please help me in getting this right

```
   def test(w, h, c, image_inp):
         output = [hwsum   for i in enumerate(image_inp)
                     hwsum += wsum for j in range(0,h)
                      wsum += image_inp[j*w + k] for k in range(0,w)
                     #image_inp[j * w + k]
                     ]
         print "Calling outprint"
         printout(output)
```

**Note:** I do not want to use numpy(with this it is working) or any math libraries.
reason being I am writing test code in python to evaluate a working on language.

**EDIT:**
input matrix will be entering the test function as 1D with w, h, c as arguments,
so it takes the form as:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12],

with w, h, c have to compute considering input1D as 3D matrix.
```

thanks

Comment: If each layer is just a list, can't you just use `sum` for each layer?

Comment: @ScottHunter, input is not a list as is, it is 1D array, have to compute 1D considering it as 3D matrix with provided, w,h,c

Comment: @kzs: Adjusted my answer to account for the 1D input array.

Comment: What is the difference between a list and a 1D array (in Python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matrix is set as your post implies with your "3D" matrix as an array of arrays:

```
M = [ [1, 2, 3,
       4, 5, 6],
     [ 7, 8, 9,
      10,11,12],
]
array_of_sums = []
for pseudo_2D_matrix in M:
    array_of_sums.append(sum(pseudo_2D_matrix))
```

If your 3D matrix, as a real three dimensional object, is set up as:

```
M = [
  [ [ 1, 2, 3],
    [ 4, 5, 6]
  ],
  [ [ 7, 8, 9],
    [10,11,12],
]
```

You could create a 1D array of sums by doing the following:

```
array_of_sums = []
for 2D_matrix in M:
    s = 0
    for row in 2D_matrix:
        s += sum(row)
    array_of_sums.append(s)
```

It's a bit unclear how your data are formatted, but hopefully you get the idea from these two examples.

**EDIT:**

In light of clarification on input you could easily accomplish this:

If dimensions `w,h,c` are given as dimensional breakout of the array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12]`, then you simply need to boundary off those regions and sum based on that:

```
input_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
w,h,c = 2,3,2
array_of_sums = []
i = 0
while i < w:
    array_of_sums.append(sum(input_array[i*h*c:(i+1)*h*c]))
    i += 1
```

as a simplified method:

```
def sum_2D_slices(w,h,c,matrix_3D):
    return [sum(matrix_3D[i*h*c:(i+1)*h*c]) for i in range(w)]
```

Comment: I have updated the details of input matrix in EDIT section. the methods explained by you are for 2D , 3D matrix as it is. I forgot to mention earlier about input.

Comment: @kzs See my edit, I have added a suggestion based on your input.

Comment: @kzs glad it worked.  I fixed a few typos in the code and added a greatly simplified method as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is very suitable for slicing and manipulating single and multiple dimensional data. It is fast, easy to use and very "pythonic".

Following your example, you can just do:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> img3d=numpy.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,12,12]]])
>>> img3d.shape
(2, 2, 3)
```

You can see here that img3d has 2 layers, 2 rows and 3 columns. You can just slice using indexing like this:

```
>>> img3d[0,:,:]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

To go from 3D to 1D, just use [numpy.flatten()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
>>> f=img3d.flatten()
>>> f
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 12, 12])
```

And reversed, use [numpy.reshape()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
>>> f.reshape((2,2,3))
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 12, 12]]])
```

Now add just jusing numpy.sum, giving the dimensions you want to add (in your case, dimensions 1 and 2 (dimensions being 0-indexed):

```
>>> numpy.sum(img3d,(1,2))
array([21, 58])
```

Just to summarize in a oneliner, you can do (variable names from your question):

```
>>> numpy.sum(numpy.array(image_inp).reshape(w,h,c),(1,2))
```

From the [numpy manual on numpy.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

> **numpy.sum**
>
> numpy.sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=numpy._globals._NoValue>)
>
> Sum of array elements over a given axis.
>
> Parameters:
>
> a : array_like Elements to sum.
>
> axis : None or int or
>   tuple of ints, optional Axis or axes along which a sum is performed.
>   The default, axis=None, will sum all of the elements of the input
>   array. If axis is negative it counts from the last to the first axis.
>
> *New in version 1.7.0.*: If axis is a tuple of ints, a sum is performed
>   on all of the axes specified in the tuple instead of a single axis or
>   all the axes as before.

Comment: While I agree this is the way to go and the way I would do this, OP did say he wants to avoid numpy...

Comment: @FarmerJoe Hmmm. I missed that. Although not really clear *why* he wants to avoid that... Thanks for the vote.

Comment: I want to write test code of my implementation in c to python. Numpy will make things abstract.